# Bulbflow: difference between neo4jserver Graph and neo4jserver Neo4jclient

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, bulbs, tinkerpop

I am now trying to learn how to connect to Neo4j server and run Cypher queries on it using Bulbflow from Python. And the thing I do not understand is the difference between two possibilities to connect to the neo4j server:

1) [Graph](http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/#graph)

```
from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
g = Graph()
```

2) [Neo4jClient](http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/neo4jserver/client/)

```
from bulbs.neo4jserver import Neo4jClient
client = Neo4jClient()
```

Could anyone please explain the conceptual difference here? 
And which way is it better to choose if I then want to execute (quite a lot of) Cypher queries against the server and ultimately in parallel?

PS: I do not have enough reputation to create a tag "bulbflow" for this question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Bulbs](http://bulbflow.com) supports three different graph database servers -- [Neo4j Server](http://www.neo4j.org/), [Rexster](http://www.tinkerpop.com/), and now [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.com/titan/).

Code specific to each backend server is contained within its own Python package (directory). You should see directories for: neo4jserver, rexster, titan:

- Bulbs Source Code: https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tree/master/bulbs

`Neo4jClient` is the low-level adapter for Neo4j Server -- you usually don't need to use this directly unless you are doing custom stuff -- use the high-level Graph class instead.

See the Bulbs docs for...

- Neo4j Server Client: http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/neo4jserver/client/
- Neo4j Server Graph:  http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/neo4jserver/graph/

The Bulbs Quickstart guide provides examples on using the `Graph` interface:

- Bulbs Quickstart: http://bulbflow.com/quickstart/

However, your Bulbs objects always have access to the low-level client when you need it via the `_client` var.

Lightbulb is an example app I created to show how to use and customize Bulbs models -- it's a Python blog engine that uses Git for source control and a graph database for persistence.

- Lightbulb: https://github.com/espeed/lightbulb

Lightbulb was originally designed for use with the free [Neo4j Heroku Add On](https://addons.heroku.com/neo4j), but both Bulbs and Lightbulb make heavy use of [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki), and the Neo4j Heroko Add On no longer offers Gremlin in the free edition.

The Lightbulb model file contains a heavily customized `Entry` model and a custom `Graph` class -- the `Entry` model makes use of the low-level client:

- Lightbulb Model: https://github.com/espeed/lightbulb/blob/master/lightbulb/model.py

As you can see in the `Entry` model, I have access to the low-level client via the `_client` var, and I use it to get a Gremlin script from the `scripts` library and then again to execute the Gremlin script.

Here's the code for the `save_blog_entry` Gremlin script used by the Entry model:

- Lightbulb Gremlin Scripts: https://github.com/espeed/lightbulb/blob/master/lightbulb/gremlin.groovy

> NOTE: There is only one Gremlin script in the file, but it is large, contains
>   several operations, and everything is wrapped in a transaction.
>   Putting all the operations into a single Gremlin script allows you to
>   do everything in one transactional request, rather than having the
>   overhead of sending multiple requests to the server.

Unless you are doing something like customizing a model, you would normally use the `scripts` object and the `gremlin` object stored on the `graph` object:

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph() 
>>> script = g.scripts.get('some_script')
>>> params = dict(name="James", city="Dallas")
>>> g.gremlin.execute(script, params)
```

See the Bulbs Neo4j Gremlin docs...

- Neo4j Gremlin: http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/neo4jserver/gremlin/

Likewise, when you want to execute a Neo4j Cypher query, use the `cypher` object stored on the `graph` object.

There are three Cypher methods (unfortunately these aren't documented on the website yet):

1. `g.cypher.query()`: Used when returning a list of nodes/relationships -- it will initialize them to objects.
2. `g.cypher.table()`: Used when returning Cypher table data.
3. `g.cypher.exectue()`: Used when returning arbitrary data -- it returns a generic `Response` object.

You can look at the source code to see how they work...

- Cypher Source: https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/cypher.py

Here are some examples of using the Cypher query() method (the query simply returns a relationship):

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph() 
>>> query = "start a = relationship({eid}) return a"
>>> params = dict(eid=123) 
>>> edges = g.cypher.query(query, params)
```

The query method automatically initializes elements to their type. If you created the element as a custom model, Bulbs will try to initialize it to the specific type, otherwise it will default to a generic `Vertex` or `Edge`.

Note that the Bulbs Cypher query() method returns an iterator.

You can loop over the iterator...

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph() 
>>> query = "start a = relationship({eid}) return a"
>>> params = dict(eid=123) 
>>> edges = g.cypher.query(query, params)
>>> for edge in edges: print edge
```

...or convert it to a list...

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph() 
>>> query = "start a = relationship({eid}) return a"
>>> params = dict(eid=123) 
>>> edges = g.cypher.query(query, params)
>>> list(edges)
```

...or get the next item...

```
>>> from bulbs.neo4jserver import Graph
>>> g = Graph() 
>>> query = "start a = relationship({eid}) return a"
>>> params = dict(eid=123) 
>>> edges = g.cypher.query(query, params)
>>> edges.next()
```

Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: The cypher query options really stumped me until I came across this. It'd be a big help to have found the .query(), .table(), and .execute() in the docs! Otherwise i'm a fan of bulbs – thanks!

Comment: Is the module still functional, since it haven't been updated for a long time?

Comment: @espeed Is bulbs no longer maintained? Initializing a `Graph()` instance is producing error.