# Choosing between py2neo and bulbs

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo, bulbs

I would like to continue the discussion started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702623/choosing-an-appropriate-way-to-use-neo4j-in-python) to evaluate these drivers: bulbs or py2neo.

Have there been any comparisons that helps one choose between the two? [This page](http://neo4j.com/developer/python/) would be greatly improved with these kinds of comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

"Optimal" is a very subjective term. Unless you're able to qualify in much more detail which features you require from a driver, your only option would be to trial both and evaluate the pros and cons for yourself.